# looping the products links for the purpose of scraping data

Tags: python, selenium

I wanted to loop through the product links from all the pages after looping, driver should open each every product link for scraping the data. For me only 1 product is opening it is not moving to next product link. Help me on this. Thanks in advance

```
import xlwt
from selenium import webdriver
import re
import time
from datetime import date

class expert:
    def __init__(self):
        self.url='https://expert938.expertonline.it/dm-IT-it/Vendita_Smartphone_W8D.aspx'
        self.country='IT'
        self.currency='euro'
        self.VAT='Included'
    def experts(self):

        wb = xlwt.Workbook()
        ws = wb.add_sheet('Sheet1',cell_overwrite_ok=True)
        ws.write(0,0,"Product_Url")
        ws.write(0,1,"Product_Manufacturer")
        ws.write(0,2,"Product_Model")
        ws.write(0,3,"Product_color")
        ws.write(0,4,"Product_memory")
        ws.write(0,5,"Product_Price")
        ws.write(0,6,"Currency")
        ws.write(0,7,"VAT")
        ws.write(0,8,"Shipping Cost")
        ws.write(0,9,"Country")
        ws.write(0,10,"Date")
        wb.save(r"C:\Users\Karthick R\Desktop\VS code\expert938.xls")
        driver=webdriver.Chrome()            
        driver.get(self.url)
        today = date.today()
        time.sleep(5)
        driver.maximize_window()                    
        while True:             
            containers = []
            flag = False
            containers =driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('div[class="col-xs-12 skywalker_riga skywalker_riga_articolo"]')                 
            for container in containers:                
                url = container.find_element_by_css_selector('div[class="text-center relative-container"]')
                urls = url.find_element_by_tag_name('a').get_attribute('href')
                product_links = []
                #print(urls)
                product_links.append(urls)
                print(product_links)
                for links in product_links:
                    driver.get(links)
                    time.sleep(10)
            break
expertit=expert()
expertit.experts()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing from

```py
url = container.find_element_by_css_selector('div[class="text-center relative-container"]')
```

to

```py
url = container.find_element_by_xpath('.//div[@class="text-center relative-container"]')
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried the below code with little tweak :

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(driver_path)
driver.maximize_window()
driver.implicitly_wait(30)
driver.get("https://expert938.expertonline.it/dm-IT-it/Vendita_Smartphone_W8D.aspx")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
containers = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='col-xs-12 skywalker_riga skywalker_riga_articolo']")
i = 1
product_links = []
for container in containers:
    url = container.find_element_by_xpath(f"(//div[@class='col-xs-12 skywalker_riga skywalker_riga_articolo']/descendant::div[contains(@class,'relative-container')]/a)[{i}]").get_attribute('href')
    i = i + 1
    product_links.append(url)

print(product_links)
```

and got this **output** :

> ['https://expert938.expertonline.it/dm-IT-it/iPhone-11-64GB-2020-_EXP729191.aspx',
> 'https://expert938.expertonline.it/dm-IT-it/iPhone-11-64GB-2020-_EXP729190.aspx',
> 'https://expert938.expertonline.it/dm-IT-it/iPhone-11-64GB-2020-_EXP729189.aspx',
> 'https://expert938.expertonline.it/dm-IT-it/OPPO-A16CRYSTALBLACK_EXP754142.aspx',
> 'https://expert938.expertonline.it/dm-IT-it/OPPO-A16PEARLBLUE_EXP754143.aspx',
> 'https://expert938.expertonline.it/dm-IT-it/C20232DARKBLUE_EXP751967.aspx',
> 'https://expert938.expertonline.it/dm-IT-it/POWER-U20_EXP749758.aspx',
> 'https://expert938.expertonline.it/dm-IT-it/POWER-U10_EXP749759.aspx',
> 'https://expert938.expertonline.it/dm-IT-it/POWER-U10_EXP749761.aspx',
> 'https://expert938.expertonline.it/dm-IT-it/POWER-U10_EXP749760.aspx',
> 'https://expert938.expertonline.it/dm-IT-it/POWER-U20_EXP749757.aspx',
> 'https://expert938.expertonline.it/dm-IT-it/REDMI-NOTE-10-5G-128GB-CHROME-SILVER_EXP748139.aspx',
> 'https://expert938.expertonline.it/dm-IT-it/X60-PRO_EXP747150.aspx',
> 'https://expert938.expertonline.it/dm-IT-it/Y72_EXP747155.aspx',
> 'https://expert938.expertonline.it/dm-IT-it/V21_EXP747153.aspx',
> 'https://expert938.expertonline.it/dm-IT-it/X60-PRO_EXP747151.aspx',
> 'https://expert938.expertonline.it/dm-IT-it/V21_EXP747152.aspx',
> 'https://expert938.expertonline.it/dm-IT-it/Y72_EXP747154.aspx',
> 'https://expert938.expertonline.it/dm-IT-it/MI-11I-8-256GB_EXP746932.aspx',
> 'https://expert938.expertonline.it/dm-IT-it/XIAOMI-MI-11-LITE-5G-128GB_EXP746078.aspx', 'https://expert938.expertonline.it/dm-IT-it/iPhone-12-mini-64GB_EXP745681.aspx',
> 'https://expert938.expertonline.it/dm-IT-it/iPhone-12-64GB_EXP745686.aspx',
> 'https://expert938.expertonline.it/dm-IT-it/REDMI-NOTE-10-5G-128GB-NIGHTTIME-BLUE_EXP745322.aspx',
> 'https://expert938.expertonline.it/dm-IT-it/REDMI-NOTE-10S-6-128GB_EXP744826.aspx',
> 'https://expert938.expertonline.it/dm-IT-it/REDMI-NOTE-10S-6-128GB_EXP744824.aspx',
> 'https://expert938.expertonline.it/dm-IT-it/M11-LITE-5G-128GB-VERDE_EXP744822.aspx',
> 'https://expert938.expertonline.it/dm-IT-it/REDMI-NOTE-10S-6-128GB_EXP744825.aspx',
> 'https://expert938.expertonline.it/dm-IT-it/8-6-128GB-5G-BLACK_EXP744698.aspx',
> 'https://expert938.expertonline.it/dm-IT-it/C21_EXP744696.aspx',
> 'https://expert938.expertonline.it/dm-IT-it/REALME-8_EXP744695.aspx',
> 'https://expert938.expertonline.it/dm-IT-it/8-6-128GB-5G-BLUE_EXP744699.aspx',
> 'https://expert938.expertonline.it/dm-IT-it/A74-Prism-Black_EXP742935.aspx',
> 'https://expert938.expertonline.it/dm-IT-it/A74-Midnight-Blue_EXP742936.aspx',
> 'https://expert938.expertonline.it/dm-IT-it/Y62-W-K610-LIGHT-BLUE_EXP742397.aspx',
> 'https://expert938.expertonline.it/dm-IT-it/Y62-W-K610-DARK-BLUE_EXP742396.aspx',
> 'https://expert938.expertonline.it/dm-IT-it/Y62-W-K610-_EXP742398.aspx']
>
> Process finished with exit code 0